# Why do I get 404 Not Found when adding this repository to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: debian, apt

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch main 
deb-src http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch main
```

When I run `sudo apt update` I see

```
Ign:10 http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch InRelease                                                         
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                
Err:12 http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch Release                                     
  404  Not Found
E: The repository 'http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
```

EDIT: The error appears to be that there is no Release file. Is there a way to still download the package?

And when I run `sudo apt install rumd` I get

```
E: Unable to locate package rumd
```

The [repository](http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd/), however, seems perfectly accessible. What is going on? I am on Debian 9.4 stretch.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that repositories that do not provide a release file are now considered insecure by default. You *may* be able to work around it by passing the `Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories` option or (perhaps better) marking the specific repo as `[trusted=yes]` in your sources.list. See `man apt-secure` for further details and make sure you understand the security implications.

Comment: Thanks, I added `[trusted=yes]`. I see (among other, ignored, sources): `Get:21 http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch/main amd64 Packages [1,587 B]` when I run `apt update`. However, if I run `apt install rumd` (as per their download page), I still get `E: Unable to locate package rumd`. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any foreign architectures enabled? `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: ... if so, try making that `deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes]` and then running `apt update` again

Answer (score 0):

> The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found and 404 error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

The above is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

In your case, maybe you don't have connection to that page.
You can just get another source.list and have a try.
Hint: you can use the source in your country, which is faster in most case.

Comment: It says "E: The repository 'http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd stretch Release' does not have a Release file." Maybe that is the problem? I have an internet connection, what do you mean "maybe I don't have connection to that page?"

Comment: @Kappie001 Just open that file and change the source. That's all what you can do.

Comment: What do you mean "change the source?"

Comment: I know how to edit a file from the command line. I cannot make out what your proposed solution to my problem is, though. Change http://debian.ruc.dk/rumd into *what*, exactly?